# Shape of graph for co-purchased items

Tags: graph-theory

I have a database containing orders from a e-commerce site where:

```
    order id      items_purchased
    order_num_1   [a,b,c] 
    order_num_2   [b,d,a] 
    order_num_3   [z,x,y]
```

I am confused on the structure of the graph showing the relationship of products to products -- Specifically, if I should take the cartesian product  of each order --example for order_num_1

```
  edge   node 
   a        a
   a        b 
   a        c 
   b        a 
   b        b 
   b        c 
   c        a 
   c        b 
   c        c
```

Or if it can be represented simply as :

```
  edge      node 
  a          a 
  a          b 
  a          c
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to check my understanding of your question. Here, you want the items in a given purchase to be vertices, and use edges to relate two items if they are in the same order. In that case, why not use a complete graph $K_{n}$? If you wanted to have a self-loop edge for each vertex in the order, you could. I think it would be a bit unnecessary, personally.

Comment: The self loop is not necessary and can be eliminated. Seeing as order_num_1 and order_num_3 have no edges -- my understanding is a complete graph does not capture the correct relationship

Comment: Can you explain why a complete graph does not capture the relationship? Perhaps could you be a bit more exacting as to the relationship?

Comment: In the above example, z,x,y contain no edges with a,b,c, or D. The edges between products represent items that were purchased together in an order. I believe the graph of each order would be a complete graph, and was unclear if I needed to model this with a cartesion prodcut (see first example) or if the edges needed to be bi-directional. Example: B-D and D-B

Comment: I'm not sure a Cartesian product is appropriate, as that implies directedness of the edges, and I don't see what you would gain from that. Your original question was unclear, and still is a bit unclear. So to make sure- if for any order o, if a, b were in o, then $\{a, b\} \in E(G)$? That sounds like your relationship right there to me.

Comment: the end result I am looking to capture is something like this: {a,(ab,ac}, {b,(bd,ba)}. Im confused in how to represent the edge between a and b in that (a,b) is not the same as (b,a) when determining the jaccard index between the sets of edges